# How to remove all break point in netbeans in selected projects only

Tags: java, netbeans, breakpoints, netbeans-8

I have 10 project in netbeans8. How to remove all break point in selected projects only.

Comment: `Window -> Debugging -> Breakpoints` , maybe possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can group breakpoints in several ways, the method above may be helps you.

Open breakpoint window by selecting menu Window/Debugging/Breakpoint (or hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>). You can select breakpoint groups with grouping button on left side of window.